# Where was the arithmetic zeta function of a scheme first defined?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ho.history-overview, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be an arithmetic scheme, that is, a scheme of finite type over the integers. We denote the set of closed points of $X$ by $|X|$. For every $x\in|X|$, write $N(x)$ for the cardinality of the residue field $\kappa(x)$.

The *arithmetic zeta function* of $X$ is defined as
$$\zeta_X(s)=\prod_{x\in|X|}\frac{1}{1-N(x)^{-s}}.$$

This definition (up to a change in variable) can be found in

> A. Grothendieck, Formule de Lefschetz et rationalité des fonctions $L$, *Séminaire Bourbaki*  279 (1964), 41-55.

Grothendieck attributes this definition to Weil, but as far as I know, Weil only defined the *Hasse-Weil zeta function*: if $X$ is a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $N_r=|X(\mathbb{F}_{q^r})|$, then
$$Z_X(t)=\exp\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty N_r(X)\frac{t^r}{r}\right).$$

Of course, it is easy to show these two functions satisfy
$$\zeta_X(s)=Z_X(q^{-s}),$$
but Weil did not address the notion of the zeta function of a scheme, at least not in the original paper:

> A. Weil, Numbers of solutions of equations in finite fields, *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* 55 (1949), 497-508.

Where was the zeta function *of an arithmetic scheme* first defined? If anyone knows the actual paper in which this first appears, that would be optimal. (Of course, it's very possible that this definition was well-known but unpublished for some time; that would be an acceptable answer too.)

Comment: The earliest reference I know of is Serre's "Zeta and L-functions", Arithm. Alg. Geom., Proc. Conf. Purdue Univ. 1963, 82-92 (1965), <http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gvcn0vT8X1QC&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=serre+zeta+and+l-functions&source=bl&ots=HH6qqPBVJI&sig=kMt1euhatMtQfuSW1cvJArgj05o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=19xEUaufGeKJ0AWfQQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=serre%20zeta%20and%20l-functions&f=false>. There he defines zeta-functions of general schemes and proves some basic properties.

Comment: You are looking for the Hasse-Weil zeta function of a variety over a number field. With a change of language, one can also call this the zeta function of the arithmetic scheme over the ring of integers defined by the variety. I don't know when the Hasse-Weil zeta function was first considered, but already by about 1950 Deuring knew how to express the Hasse-Weil zeta function of a CM elliptic curve in terms of Hecke characters. There's probably no first paper --- if you look hard enough you can find such a zeta function in the work of Gauss.

Answer (score 5):

I accidentally found the answer to this question in the book "[The Abel Prize. 2003-2007 The First Five Years](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642013720)", page 74:

> "A first lecture on zeta and L-functions in the setting of the theory
>   of schemes (of finite type over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$) was given
>   by Serre in [S112, 64(1965)]."

The paper is, of course,

- Jean-Pierre Serre, Zeta and L functions (1965) Arithmetical Algebraic Geometry (Proc. Conf. Purdue Univ., 1963) pp. 82-92 Harper & Row, New York [also in Collected Papers, vol. II, n° 64)]

This confirms Tim Dokchitser comment.

On a side note, the concept of scheme didn't even exist at the time of Weil's paper!